# Which JWT + Spring Security configuration method is relevant right now?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

At the moment I am developing an authorization server using spring security + OAUTH2 and JWT, but in the examples there are many different ways, some of them are deprecated.
Tell me, please, the most current?

When creating a project, I plug dependency the Cloud OAuth2, then a dependency appears in

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I also customize the annotating @EnableAuthorizationServer

I use this method, tell me how relevant is it?
I saw other ways where it was necessary to register and configure filters, providers, etc., this is closer to me, but I don’t understand which option is the most relevant now.